# Firebase inconsistent data structure

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am assessing Firebase as a replacement for Parse in my current app. However I have come across an issue when querying remote data.

When I retrieve a query I am getting an inconsistent data structure back.

My realtime data looks like this:

[image]
[image]

Previously in Parse the Bool values set up for 'Beef, chicken, pork'  would have just been held in an array and I would query based on the array containing that item for each row. However as Firebase advises Arrays are bad in JSON I have had to implement them as Bool's and query based on they property, so my query looks like this

```
 FIRDatabaseReference *ref =  [[FIRDatabase database] reference];     

    FIRDatabaseReference *path = [ref child:@"recipes"];

    FIRDatabaseQuery *query1 = [path queryOrderedByChild:@"beef"];

    FIRDatabaseQuery *query2 = [query1 queryEqualToValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
    [query2 observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
        [self hideSpinner];
        NSArray *recipes = (NSArray *)snapshot.value;
```

The initial query works fine and the data comes back as follows

[image]

However, if I amend the query to :

```
[path queryOrderedByChild:@"pork"];
```

The data structure is completely different,

[image]

yet it comes from exactly the same json as the previous entry - has anyone experienced anything similar? its driving me nuts

Comment: Use arrays.  There's nothing wrong with arrays in JSON.

Comment: @Avi I have never had a problem with arrays in JSON, however I couldnt find anything in Firebases documentation around retrieving items if they included an item in an array  - & even if there is a a way to do this, I am concerned that the data I will get back will still be inconsistent as above.

Comment: Because I have not been able to find any firebase methods to support the query - happy to try it, however need to be able to create the correct query

Comment: Oh.  That's annoying.  I haven't used FirebaseDB, but overall I am not impressed with their offerings.  This sounds like just another reason.

Comment: @Avi it looks like a reasonable service, but I am definitely finding some implementation issues when trying to migrate over. I am thinking of looking at another service TBH

Comment: Honestly?  I would.  Also, they are owned by Google now, and Google has never been concerned with offering iOS a great experience.

Comment: *firebaser here* I hope our documentation doesn't say that array are bad in JSON. They're a perfectly valid construct there. If our docs say otherwise, please point me to them. But in a multi-user, collaborative database, using arrays are often the cause of scalability problems.

Comment: On your actual question: if you ask for the data in a certain order, the returned data will contain additional information about the order of the items returned. Since JSON properties are inherently unordered, this leads to a different data structure. But if you simply loop over the items with `for childSnapshot in snapshot.children` you will get each item in the same format as before.

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen my problem is that the 2 queries are on the same object, just checking for matches on a different property. So by changing the property from "beef" to "Pork" I get a completely different data structure. Essentially all I need to do is get recipes that match a category - is there no simple way to do this that returns a consistent data structure?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - I understand the point regarding concurrent editing of arrays, however in this case, this data will not be editable by multiple users, so is a good use case for an array and appropriate query to see if an item is contained the array  - page I was referring to states "Firebase has no native support for arrays. If we try to store an array, it really gets stored as an "object" with integers as the key names." https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/understanding-data.html

Comment: That statement from the docs is correct and accurate. It does not imply you shouldn't use an array, just warns that we find an over-use of them. In many cases the arrays are better represented in Firebase as lists of so-called push id keyed items (using `childByAutoId`) or sets, where the values in the array become the keys: `ingredients: { beef: true, chicken: true, ketchup: true }`. The latter is easier to check for the existence of a key and to prevent the same item being present multiple times. Did my explanation of why the result looks different with a query make sense btw?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen hey thanks for the reply - the response didn't really make sense to be honest - I am having difficulty reasoning with having to handle multiple response types for the same query - if I send a query I really expect to get the same response back each time, I have never seen this in other frameworks

Comment: Or perhaps I am calling the wrong method? is there a method where I can call to check the property on each child of an object and only return the ones that are true ? one that returns a consistent data structure each time?

Comment: Queries and location references return the same data, but a query also needs to return the order in which the items occur in the result. If you loop over the children with `for childSnapshot in snapshot.children`, it works the same way for both cases.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks that loop solves the issue -  It feels messy though  - also I don't get why the "beef" query doesnt show the same data structure as this surely should contain the order etc